# sql query only show the result when they have differnt count of values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like the query returns the result that has differnt count(action)

```
Sample data
    ID      Action
1   125317  ADD
2   125317  ADD
3   125317  ADD
4   125317  ADD
5   125317  ADD
6   125317  ADD
7   125317  ADD
8   125317  CLEAN
9   125317  CLEAN
10  125317  CLEAN
11  125317  CLEAN
12  125317  CLEAN
13  125317  CLEAN
14  125317  CLEAN
15  359905  ADD
16  359905  ADD
17  359905  ADD
18  359905  CLEAN
```

my query currently can get the folliwng..

```
    ID  ACTION   COUNT1
1   359905  ADD    3
2   359905  CLEAN  1
3   125317  ADD    7
4   125317  CLEAN  7
```

However, I only want it returen row 1 and row2 only since the count1 is differnt.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the ids, you can use aggregation and count in the `having` clause:

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having sum(action = 'add') <> sum(action = 'clean');
```

If you want the counts, I would put them in the `select` clause:

```
select id, sum(action = 'add') as adds, sum(action = 'clean') as cleans
from table t
group by id
having sum(action = 'add') <> sum(action = 'clean');
```

Comment: here is my current query    select t.id, t.action, count(t.action) as count1 from table t where t.id=125317 or t.id= 359905 group by t.id,t.action        ;How can i add on your parts to my query?

Comment: @tyyt2010 . . . That is a significant change to the question.  You should ask another question and reference this one.